# How can I use any pod in a Keurig 2.0?

Tags: keurig

I have a Keurig 2.0 machine, that won't accept anything but authorised coffee pods. I've read that this 'feature' can be bypassed. How do I go about using my own coffee pods with this machine?

Answer (score 6):

The Keurig 2.0 machine is looking for an element (perhaps magnetic?) that is embedded in the authorized pods. The site [KeurigHack.com](http://www.keurighack.com/) contains a video that shows a simple technique for bypassing this feature.

Basically you need one lid from an authorized pod that you can place on top of your pods so that the Keurig 2.0 accepts these pods. The video goes on to show that it's fairly easy to make this a permanent change just by applying some tape to your authorized lid so that it sticks to the roof of the pod enclosure. The following screenshots were taken from the video. Enjoy!

Step 1: Get an authorized lid.
[image]

Step 2: Place lid over any other pod.
[image]